# Can't add work file to a Company-owned devices for work and personal use

Tags: android-management-api

I've created a token with this policy:

```
{
      "name": "enterprises/LC0261d9zr/policies/CompanyOwnedWorkProfilePolicy1",
      "version": "1",
      "applications": [
        {
          "packageName": "com.google.android.gm",
          "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
          "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
        },
        {
          "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.docs",
          "installType": "AVAILABLE"
        }
      ],
      "passwordRequirements": {
        "passwordMinimumLength": 6,
        "passwordQuality": "ALPHABETIC"
      },
      "usbFileTransferDisabled": true,
      "bluetoothDisabled": true,
      "personalUsagePolicies": {
        "cameraDisabled": true,
        "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
        "maxDaysWithWorkOff": 3,
        "personalPlayStoreMode": "BLACKLIST"
      }
    },
```

and set `"allowPersonalUsage": "PERSONAL_USAGE_ALLOWED"`,
I got enrollment token successfully, and use DPC indentifier to register a device.
But at last, the device shows :
Can't add work profile :  A work profile can't be added to this device.If you have questions,contact your admin.

Can someone tell me what's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

PS: I've successfully set the device as Company-owned devices for work use only.
After factory-reset, and I wanna set the device to Company-owned devices for work and personal use,I met this problem.
My phone's system is 8.0

I've also tried to use another enrollment token with policy below to set the device as Personally-owned devices,get the same result.

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC0261d9zr/policies/PersonalyOwnedProfilePolicy1",
  "version": "1",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.google.android.gm",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.docs",
      "installType": "AVAILABLE"
    }
  ],
  "passwordRequirements": {
    "passwordMinimumLength": 6,
    "passwordQuality": "ALPHABETIC"
  }
}
```

Comment: It is about 2 days, can someone give me an advice?

Comment: It is android go system, can't add work-file.